# API service return 200, but it is really a 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have this VUEJS / VUEJS Resources snippet that is fetching data from an API service.

```
fetchData: function(name){
          var self = this;
          self.$http.get('http://www.apiservice.com/', {
            params: {
               city: name
            },
            }).then((response) => {
            // success callback
            toastr.success('Success!');
            console.debug(response);
          }, (response) => {
             // error
            toastr.error('Something went wrong!')
          });
        }
```

And it will always return a 200 OK response... So i don't really know how to show the `toastr.error`, if its always a "success".

The false response looks like this: `{Response: "False", Error: "City not found!"}`.

## My question

How can I fetch the `false` in the Response of a 200 ok return, and throw an error?

Comment: Unless your api server returns 404 in response, you cannot do that without using some kind of hack (i.e check your response and invoke error function from there if the response you received is not what you expected).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like bad API design to return a "no response found" as HTTP 200, but if you have no control over the API, you'll just have to handle that in your success function.

Put your error handling code in a function and call it accordingly:

```
fetchData: function(name){
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('http://www.apiservice.com/', {
    params: {
       city: name
    },
    }).then((response) => {
        // success callback
        if (response.Response === "False") {
            onError(response)
        } else {
            toastr.success('Success!');
            console.debug(response);
        }
    }, onError);
}

function onError(response) {
   toastr.error('Something went wrong!') 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onError`, the line `}, onError);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use promise chaining to switch a promise from resolve to reject:

```
fetchData: function(name){
          var self = this;
          self.$http.get('http://www.apiservice.com/', {
            params: {
              city: name
            },
            }).then(response)=>{
              if(response.Response === "False"){
                return Promise.reject(response)
              }else{
                return response
              }
            },(a)=>a).then((response) => {
              // success callback
              toastr.success('Success!');
              console.debug(response);
            }, (response) => {
              // error
              toastr.error('Something went wrong!')
            });
        }
```

The important part is this:

```
then(response)=>{
  if(response.Response === "False"){
    return Promise.reject(response)
  }else{
    return response
  }
},(a)=>a)
```

so if the response is valid, and the data contains `Response: "False"` we return a rejected promise, otherwise we just return the response data, which is then wrapped in a resolved promise, after that the next `then` executes as before, but invalid data has already been rejected.